# Is there a way to choose/ stay in one specific flutter version for one app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

With Flutter 2 just released, I want to upgrade the SDK to the latest stable version, but I won't do it, since there will be compatibility issue with some of the plugin that I use. Is there a way to choose/ stay in a specific flutter version for one app so that when I upgrade my SDK it won't disrupt my existing app? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Now, i believe Laravel has a way to choose the specific version for the web app. Does flutter have it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe fvm is what you need. I am also looking into this so might have more info soon. According to info from pubdev it can "Configure and use Flutter SDK version per project" Check the pubdev for more info
https://pub.dev/packages/fvm

Answer (score 0):

No, currently you cannot do that. You should just upgrade your SDK after about a month or so when support for Flutter 2.0 would be out for most packages I guess